# Unable to detect touch inside internet explorer or microsoft edge

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, hook, microsoft-edge

I have setup a global hook for WH_GETMESSAGE and WH_CALLWNDPROC. And I am trying to detect touch made on the screen. I am able to do so for everything that's there in the screen except for Microsoft Edge and the client area of Internet Explorer.

By that, I mean I am unable to detect if somebody touches an open edge or the client area of an Internet Explorer Window. But the same works for Google Chrome or other browsers. Any idea why this is happening and what should my approach be, to deal with it?

I have shared a portion of my hook proc code below.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK GetMsgProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (lpMsg->message)
    {
    case WM_POINTERDOWN:
        UINT32 pointerId = GET_POINTERID_WPARAM(lpMsg->wParam);
        POINTER_INPUT_TYPE pointerType;
        GetPointerType(pointerId, &pointerType);
 
        if (pointerType == PT_TOUCH)
        {
                   MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Its a touch"), TEXT("In a DLL"), MB_OK);
 

        }
        return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> To hook all applications on the desktop of a 64-bit Windows
>   installation, install a 32-bit global hook and a 64-bit global hook,
>   each from appropriate processes, and be sure to keep pumping messages
>   in the hooking application to avoid blocking normal functioning. If
>   you already have a 32-bit global hooking application and it doesn't
>   need to run in each application's context, you may not need to create
>   a 64-bit version.

The above extract is from somewhere in the below mentioned link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx